# Capturing Image using ActivityResultLauncher does not return to the activity that's called in, else it returns to main activity after capturing image

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm trying to capture an image in an Activity using ActivityResultLauncher. the image is captured but after pressing confirm. the app doesn't go back to the screen I launched the camera from, rather than it goes to the main screen.

```
public void captureImage(){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Cust-" + customerName+ newCustomerID);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From the Camera");
    image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    cameraActivityResultLauncher.launch(image_uri);
}

ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> cameraActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
                if(result) {
                    Bitmap inputImage = uriToBitmap(image_uri);
                    Bitmap rotated = rotateBitmap(inputImage);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(rotated);
                }

            }
        });



//TODO takes URI of the image and returns bitmap
private Bitmap uriToBitmap(Uri selectedFileUri) {
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(selectedFileUri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  null;
}

//TODO rotate image if image captured on samsung devices
//TODO Most phone cameras are landscape, meaning if you take the photo in portrait, the resulting photos will be rotated 90 degrees.
@SuppressLint("Range")
public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap input){
    String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(image_uri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
    int orientation = -1;
    if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
        orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
    }
    Log.d("tryOrientation",orientation+"");
    Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
    rotationMatrix.setRotate(orientation);
    Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(input,0,0, input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), rotationMatrix, true);
    return cropped;
}
```

Logcat:

> Handler (com.samsung.android.camera.core2.device.CamDeviceHandlerManager$ExecTimeLoggingHandler) {8f36486} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (com.samsung.android.camera.core2.device.CamDeviceHandlerManager$ExecTimeLoggingHandler) {8f36486} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
> at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:560)
> at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:778)
> at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:727)
> at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:697)
> at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:427)
> at com.samsung.android.camera.core2.device.CamDeviceImpl.lambda$createCaptureSessionInternal$2(CamDeviceImpl.java:634)
> at com.samsung.android.camera.core2.device.-$$Lambda$CamDeviceImpl$5X5wiAbd03qI4TTgkJV3Zs0XzuA.accept(Unknown Source:4)
> at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:179)
> at com.samsung.android.camera.core2.device.CamDeviceImpl.lambda$createCaptureSessionInternal$3$CamDeviceImpl(CamDeviceImpl.java:634)
> at com.samsung.android.camera.core2.device.-$$Lambda$CamDeviceImpl$ckQoqhLVTrOTDJwKo66Y0V6AUsk.execute(Unknown Source:2)
> at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CallbackProxies$SessionStateCallbackProxy.onReady(CallbackProxies.java:74)
> at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onIdle(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:843)
> at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$6.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:244)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

Comment: Please post the logcat lines in a normal way in a code block preserving lines.

Comment: @blackapps i've posted the logcat

Comment: Yes, but unreadable. Post it in the normal way was the comment.